# Ajax onclick wont work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a form with a checkbox and when clicking this checkbox, some ajax should be submitting.

It is not working and I have been staring blind on this for hours. I hope someone out there can tell me why it doesn't work. Thanks in advance. The code is below

```
<td>
  <form method="POST" action="" class="insertLike">
    <input type="checkbox" class="safeBetCheck" name="safeBet" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
</td>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo$preBetFeed['id'];?>">
  </form>

var check = $('.safeBetCheck');

var formLike = $('.insertLike').serialize();

$('input').on('click',function(){
 if (check.is(':checked')){

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "trusted.php",
      data: formData,
      success: function(formLike){
        alert('yeah!');
      }
    });


  }
  else {
    alert('no');
  }

});
```

Comment: Is the variable "formData" defined anywhere?

Comment: Well first of all, your `<form>` and `<td>` HTML tags are not properly closed. The `td` should be closed after `<form>`

Comment: Are you getting any error in the browser console?

Comment: @Brad I think `formLike` is supposed to be his `formData` but you're write. `formData` has not been defined.

Comment: You spent hours debugging it without opening your console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `formdata` with `formLike`

```
var check = $('.safeBetCheck');

var formLike = $('.insertLike').serialize();

$('input').on('click',function(){
 if (check.is(':checked')){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "trusted.php",
  data: formLike,
  success: function(formLike){
    alert('yeah!');
  }
});


}
else{
  alert('no');
}

});
```